# Submitted app with wrong release provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have been distributing the app for test purposes with an adhoc provisioning profile to a set of users. This provile I set under Code Signing- Provisioning Profile - Release...

Now I have createed the archive to submit to iTunes App Store accidentally with this provisioning profile - instead of a distribution provisioning profile

(the code signing identity is still a distribution one)

What does that mean?
Is this a problem?
Will only those users be able to install the app and run it that are in the ad hoc provisioning profile?

So basically do I need to reject the binary before its too late - I have been waiting long time now and do not want to resubmit if its not necessary

Many thanks

Comment: Was this done in Xcode 5?

Comment: yes 5.0.2 - really bad that it even was accepted by Apple's smart verification check during the upload procedure. Anyway I rejected the binary now I feel it's too dangerous to try it out ;-) So I will not be able to tell you the outcome of this.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571573/submitting-ad-hoc-app-to-appstore-itunesconnect